# Screen readers and JavaScript print feature

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers

I have written a JavaScript-based print feature for a web page. It extracts HTML from a hidden div on the page, renders it into a new window and triggers the print dialog.

The option is made available over a `button` with an `onclick="printTheThing()"` event. I know that for example screen readers have some caveats with JavaScript. **I am wondering whether/how many people such as blind or vision-impaired I block from using this feature.**

The implementation opens a new browser window and appends to its document:

```
function printTheThing() {
    var dispSettings = "toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"
        + "scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=400",
        html = $('#theDivToPrint').html(),
        printWindow = window.open("", "", dispSettings),
        doc = printWindow.document;

    doc.open();
    try {
        doc.write('<html><head>');
        doc.write('<title>' + title + '</title>');
        doc.write('</head><body>');
        doc.write(html);
        doc.write('</body></html>');
    } finally {
        doc.close();
    }
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
}
```

Update: This is what the button looks like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="printTheThing()">Print the thing!</button>
```

In addition, I am using CSS to replace the button by an image. I have tested the button with the Firefox plug-in "Fangs". It suggests that screen-readers will perfectly read out the original button text. But Fangs does not provide any interactivity so I cannot test the printing with it.

Comment: How about trying out yourself? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn

Comment: like that :-) add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to improve accessibility by using screen readers use W3C WAI-ARIA live regions, for more info see [their recommendations](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/)  and [FAQ](http://www.w3.org/WAI/aria/faq).

to test you can use the following screen readers:
on Windows - JAWS, NVDA
on Linux - orca (is not working with Chromium) + advice of Florian Margaine

you can also use [AChecker](http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) to test on compliance of WCAG 2.0, Section 508, Stanca Act accessibility standards.

Comment: This is good information, but not really relevant to the original question: WAI-ARIA Live regions are specifically for areas of a page that update in real-time, such as tickers and news feeds the like. The OP is more concerned about whether basic javascript will work with screenreaders (short answer: yes, but test to confirm).

Comment: Thanks, dae. Although some of the hints are not directly related to my question, some are. BTW: I decided to go for a non-JavaScript way even though it might be supported by ScreenReaders, because there are other reasons to make a web site run without JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome extension shouldn't be relied on at all. You should test stuff with NVDA, which is free. I will guess that Google fanboys will say Chrome Vox is fine. Trust me, I have been working with AT for nearly 15 years.

Anyway, I would need to see the code for the button, not the JS... The JS looks fine. Some people have trouble with knowing there is a new window, however the print dialog should grab focus versus the window

Comment: NVDA for Windows, Orca for Linux, VoiceOver for OS X. And +1 to your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the +1s! @chiccodoro, the HTML looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is surely to try it out yourself.

There is a Google Chrome extension allowing you this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn

Answer (score 1):

The way to render a printable page is to use `@media` CSS directives. That way you don't need to do anything special like pop-up another window or worry about accessibility: the content is simply printed correctly (and possibly very differently from the on-screen layout, if that's what you want).

Comment: well this is not simply about a printer-friendly layout. I only want to print a small piece of the information from the page, and this only holds true for that very button. If the user chooses to File->Print the page, the whole page should be printed.